# How can I reload partial frequently using Ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

In background, I want it to reload and shows the number how many unread messages are there.
I want that without refreshing page.  I mean using ajax.

If I had this in menu, how can I refresh only this section every 30 secs?

```
<li><%= link_to sanitize('<i class="icon-envelope"></i> ') + "received messages" + sanitize(' <span class="badge badge-info">'+current_user.mailbox.inbox(:read => false).count(:id, :distinct => true).to_s+'</span>'), messages_received_path  %></li>
```

messages_controller.rb

```
  def received
    if params[:search]
     @messages = current_user.mailbox.inbox.search_messages(@search).page(params[:page]).per(10)
    else
     @messages = current_user.mailbox.inbox.page(params[:page]).per(10)
    end 
     add_crumb 'Messages Received', messages_received_path

     @box = 'inbox'
     render :index
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

**controller**

```
def messages_received
  @messages = Messages.messages_received
  respond_to |format|
   format.json { render json: @messages }
  end
end
```

**js**

```
 setInterval(function(){
   $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/messages_received',
        data: {},
        success: function(JSONRESPONSE){
            alert(JSONRESPONSE)  // @messages variable
        };
   })
 },30000)   // 30 segs
```

Comment: Thanks for help. what am I supposed to do now? Do I need to create js or somethings like that? what about view and controller??

Comment: make a partial of the information you need to update, then on your controller put this render partial: 'update/info'

Comment: Thanks for suggestion:) but what about controller and view??

Comment: Thanks:) how can I code view? and where at am I supposed to set every 30sec to update?

Comment: Thank you so much:) Actually, I have 'received action' that calls template for all kind of message actions. You showed me new action here. Once user click the link, it calls 'received action.  I have no idea how you could execute your ajax call beside that

Answer (score 1):

You should have an action which returns you something like a number of unread messages and poll it using the JS function `setInterval()`