# How can I re-render more than 2 partials at once using Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a rails app, which is constructed by three parts such as navigation above, main content, and side menu.

I already implemented follow un-follow button in my main content.
It's working with Ajax perfectly so far.

basically if I press follow button, follow action in users_controller.rb will be called and changes follow flag, and then it calls follow.js to re-render follow button as partial.
Beside that, in side menu, it has the number of people whom current_user is following.
This number also should be refreshed right after follow action was executed.

To refresh more than 2 partials at once. How can I archive this?

controllers/users_controller.rb

```
....

  def follow
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render :action=>"follow.js"}
    end
  end

  def unfollow
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    current_user.stop_following(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render :action=>"unfollow.js"}
    end
  end

...
```

views/users/follow.js.erb

```
$('.follow_user[data-user-id="<%=@user.id%>"]').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "users/follow_user", :locals => {:user => @user}) %>');
```

views/users/unfollow.js.erb

```
$('.follow_user[data-user-id="<%=@user.id%>"]').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "users/follow_user", :locals => {:user => @user}) %>');
```

views/layouts/_menu.html.erb

```
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
                  <li><%= link_to(following_user_path(current_user.username)) do %>
                  <i class="icon-heart"></i>Following
                  <%= '(' + current_user.all_following.count.to_s + ')' if current_user.all_following.count > 0 %>
                  <% end %>
                  </li>    

                  <li><%= link_to(followed_user_path(current_user.username)) do %>
                  <i class="icon-heart"></i>Followed by
                  <%= '(' + current_user.followers.count.to_s + ')' if current_user.followers.count > 0 %>
                  <% end %>
                  </li>
              <% else %>
                  <li><%= link_to sanitize('<i class="icon-heart"></i> ') + "Following", following_user_path %></li>                                            
                  <li><%= link_to sanitize('<i class="icon-heart"></i> ') + "Followed by", followed_user_path %></li>                                           

              <% end %>
```

Comment: @apneadiving how??? can you show me an example, please.

Comment: post your code: follow action in the controller, partial "number of people whom current_user is following" and follow.js. And explanation will be more understandable.

Comment: @ValeryKvon Thanks for help! I just added my coded to Question. If you could make my codes shorter and more sophisticated in _menu.html.erb, that'll be awesome!

Comment: @ValeryKvon Now it does weird movement. If I follow 2 people, it shows 1 and if I un follow both of them 1 will dissappear

Comment: i didnt mention your app logic. In js. pass current_user instead @user

Comment: @ValeryKvon Thanks you so much:) I could solve that!! Thanks again! If possible, please check my another question about Ajax ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899754/how-can-i-reload-partial-frequently-using-ajax ) this is probably easy for you

Comment: @VakeryKvon Sorry, I take it back. It's still doing weird action, It shows nothing even when current_user is followed by 1 person. But if I keep click and click and click, correct number comes back... It seems strange with synchronizing... Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @ValeryKvon it's fixed if I write inside of the help like this     current_user.all_following.count > 0 ? "(#{current_user.all_following.count})" : nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# dedicate partial _following_number.html.erb
<span id="following_number">
  <% if user.followers.count > 0 %>
    <%= '(' + user.followers.count.to_s + ')' %>
  <% end %>
</span>


# update layout with partial:

<li><%= link_to(followed_user_path(current_user.username)) do %>
<i class="icon-heart"></i>Followed by
  <%= render :partial => "following_number", :user => current_user %>
<% end %>

# follow.js.erb && unfollow.js.erb:
...
$(document).find("#following_number").replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render("following_number", :user => @user, :formats => [:html])) %>')
```

More elegant with helper:

```
def following_number(user)
  user.followers.count > 0 ? "(#{user.followers.count})" : nil
end

# then put spans to layout:
<span id="following_number"><%= following_number(current_user) %></span>

# and js:
$(document).find("#following_number").html('<%= escape_javascript(following_number(@user)) %>')
```

Comment: @VarleyKvon Thanks for help, I tried your code but it does nothing anymore when pressing follow button. and if I paste your partial _following_number.html.erb, it says the error 'un method user' so that I had to re-write to current_user instead of user:( can you think of any why it doesn't do anything.. I might think there's problem with js files

Comment: undefined method user - means you didn't pass local :user. Dont forget it: :user => current_user (layout) and :user => @user (in js.erb)

Comment: Now I tried your 2nd suggestion with helper. but it still won't work:( is your code made for rails3? or older version?

Comment: I think you missed something... detect error: what would be with: $(document).find("#following_number").html("BLABLABLA");

Comment: @VarleyKvon I found it!!!! in js, current_user should be argument instead of '@user'

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new action that `render_to_string` both of those partials and format them into a json object:

`{

  div_id_1: "<ul....." ,

  div_id_2: "<div...."

}`

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of doing this is to return a `.js` from rails and have your view execute this script, which will have the actions to update/replace your view.

For example this simply renders three partials and later using jQuery replaces the content in your view. Lets say the action is `my_action` so you will place the following code in your `my_action.js.erb`:

```
$("#content_1").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('partial_1'))%>");
$("#content_2").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('partial_2'))%>");
$("#content_3").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('partial_3'))%>");
```

This example can be extended the way you want or need. You can also render json for your models and call a function to update them in the view.

Comment: do you always need to make partial file just like _follow_number.html.erb to select the area to refresh? or you don't need to make another one if putting <div class="content_1">?

Comment: I added more info to my question so please check.